# Conditional function in a Grade Forgiveness Function

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

In this code, I think I have it nearly right, but it isn't calculating the way I need it to.
The code should ignore the first grade, only if the second is higher for a single grade.

Here is the code I've constructed for it, but when I run the program it will always calculate the second grade irregardless of its value.

```
double ComputeGPA()
    {
        if (Count == 0) return 0;
        bool bForgiven = false;
        int nCourseCount = 0;
        int i;
        double gpa = 0.0;
        double gpaToAdd;
        for (i = 0; i < this.Count; i++)
        {
            gpaToAdd = 0.0; 
            Course c = this[i]; 
            gpaToAdd = GradePoints(c.Grade);
            if (c.Grade == null || c.Grade == "W") continue;
            if (bForgiven == false)
            {
                int nRep = FindCourse(c.Number, i + 1);
                if (nRep > 0)
                {
                    Course x = this[i + 1];
                    if(GradePoints(this[nRep].Grade > GradePoints(c.Grade)))
                        gpaToAdd = GradePoints(x.Grade); 
                    // This means we forgive only one grade
                    bForgiven = true;
                    continue;
                }
            }
        gpa = gpa + GradePoints(c.Grade);
        nCourseCount++;
    }
    //If we've forgiven a grade , we divide by one less course
    gpa = (nCourseCount > 0) ? gpa / nCourseCount : 0.0;
    return gpa;
}
```

I also have these functions to work with it:

```
public int FindCourse(int Number, int nStart)
       {
           int i;
           for (i = nStart; i< this.Count; i++)
           {
               Course c = this[i];
               if (c.Number == Number) return i;
           }
           return -1; // Signifies no course was found
       }

public int FindCourse(int Number)
{
    return FindCourse(Number, 0);
}
```

What is the construct that will allow this to work?

Thank you,
Travis

Here are some test inputs:

```
TestTranscript();
    }
    static void TestTranscript()
    {
        Transcript trans = new Transcript();
        trans.Add(new Course(1, 3113, "A", false));
        trans.Add(new Course(1, 3232, "A", false));
        trans.Add(new Course(1, 4212, "A", false));
        trans.Add(new Course(1, 3113, "F", false));
        trans.Add(new Course(1, 4220, "A", false));
        trans.Add(new Course(1, 4234, "A", false));
        trans.Add(new Course(1, 4300, "A", false));
        TranscriptForm frm = new TranscriptForm("Test Transcript", trans);
        frm.ShowDialog();
        MessageBox.Show("GPA is computed to be " + trans.GPA.ToString());
    }
```

And these are their corresponding values per letter:

```
 public static double GradePoints(string grade)
    {
        switch (grade)
        {
            case "A":
            case "A+":
                return 4.0;
            case "A-":
                return 3.7;
            case "B+":
                return 3.3;
            case "B":
                return 3.0;
            case "B-":
                return 3.7;
            case "C+":
                return 2.3;
            case "C":
                return 2.0;
            case "C-":
                return 1.7;
            case "D+":
                return 1.3;
            case "D":
                return 1.0;
            case "D-":
            default:
                return 0.0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you give example inputs, and the expected outputs? I think it will make your question more clear.

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't understand your question. Can you please reform it?

Comment: I want to make a conditional function that will take overwrite the first grade value with the second grade value, but only if it is higher and only once.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Chris Shain's comments, this part looks odd to me:

```
 Course x = this[i + 1];
 if(GradePoints(this[nRep].Grade > GradePoints(c.Grade)))
   gpaToAdd = GradePoints(x.Grade);
```

Why i+1 here - isn't that what happens to be next in the list, not necessarily the same course number? Shouldn't gpaToAdd rather be the better grade (this[nRep].Grade)?

Comment: When I use (GradePoints(x.Grade)> GradePoints(c.Grade)) it will still only calculate the second grade. this[nRep].Grade was to access the previous one.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a flow control problem.  See my note on the `continue` statement:

```
for (i = 0; i < this.Count; i++)
    {
        gpaToAdd = 0.0; 
        Course c = this[i]; 
        gpaToAdd = GradePoints(c.Grade);
        if (c.Grade == null || c.Grade == "W") continue;
        if (bForgiven == false)
        {
            int nRep = FindCourse(c.Number, i + 1);
            if (nRep > 0)
            {
                Course x = this[i + 1];
                if(GradePoints(this[nRep].Grade > GradePoints(c.Grade)))
                    gpaToAdd = GradePoints(x.Grade); 
                // This means we forgive only one grade
                bForgiven = true;

                // This will restart the for loop at the next item, 
                // presumably skipping whatever code you left out
                // below
                continue; 
            }
        }

    // Something else is going on down here that you didnt show us-
    // my guess is something like:
    gpa = gpaToAdd + gpa;
    // but it is getting skipped when a grade is forgiven
```

Continue is documented here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/923ahwt1(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: OK- but you realize that will be skipped when a grade is forgiven right?

Comment: Sorry, I am really new to this.

Comment: No problem.  Try using the debugger to create a breakpoint at the beginning of the method and then step through it.  You'll see the execution go from the continue line back up to the beginning of the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issue that are causing the wrong calculation to happen.

1) As others have mentioned, the continue statement is a problem.  The thing here is that you only want it to continue (and set bForgiven) when you are skipping that item.  In other words, it needs to be included in the if statement as follows:

```
if (GradePoints(trans[nRep].Grade) > GradePoints(c.Grade))
{
    gpaToAdd = GradePoints(x.Grade);
    // This means we forgive only one grade
    bForgiven = true;
    continue;
}
```

2) You're looping through "this" with the line

```
for (i = 0; i < this.Count; i++)
```

Later you're searching for another grade for the same "c.Number" with this line

```
int nRep = FindCourse(c.Number, i + 1);
```

The issue is that you're looking for a later (in the list) Number and never comparing to earlier records, so when it gets to the first "3113" (record 0), it finds and compares against the second (record 3), but when it gets to record 3, it never finds the first because it is searching starting at record 4.

The fix for this is for FindCourse to search from the beginning up to the current so in your example it triggers hits with record 3 instead of record 0 like this.

```
public int FindCourse(int Number, int nCurrent)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < nCurrent; i++)
    {
        Course c = this[i];
        if (c.Number == Number) return i;
    }
    return -1; // Signifies no course was found
}
```

Note: This will require calling with i instead of i+1 like this.

```
int nRep = FindCourse(c.Number, i);
```

Comment: Okay, I see my mistake now and I understand why it it set up this way. My only other question is where do I reference the trans and nCurrent so the compiler recognizes it?

Comment: Sorry about the trans reference, I have edited my answer to remove its usage. nCurrent is defined in the definition of FindCourse. In your original post the int parameter was called nStart, I just renamed it to better describe its usage.